# Display currently compiling filename in gcc under linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

When compiling multiple files with gcc (i.e: gcc *.c), a large project may take some time to compile and, if no errors are found, the screen remains static for some time. Does gcc have a command line option to display the filename of the c file its currently compiling?

Comment: What about the gcc documentation is missing? If you have a laerger project, using a build-tool like SCons or the classic make would be the way to go anyway

Comment: If you have multiple source files, I recommend you learn about the `make` command to compile each source file into separate *object files* that you then *link* together into a single executable. The `make` program by default displays the commands it executes, giving you a sense of progress. But also, it enables you to have dependencies, so you don't have to rebuild all sources if you just change a single file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: As a sidenote: There are better and more reliable build-tools than make. It's only advantage is it is installed by default on Unixoids. Beginners are often better of with e.g. SCons, experts can do a lot more as it is all Python (SCons and the control files).

Comment: @Olaf Yes there is, but as you say it's installed by default on all Unix-y systems, and is good to learn understand the basics which can be brought into other more advanced tools.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: SCons is as much "more advanced" as Python is: Both are easier to learn than e.g. Java or make, but also more powerful. They somewhat grow with the experience. make has a pretty steep learning curve and not much more to discover afterwards. E.g. SCons find dependencies automatically without additional effort. And it is part of all Linux distributions; Other Unix systems are hardly used by beginners anyway.

Comment: Once upon a long time ago (I mean back in the last millennium, and not necessarily the last decade of the last millennium), compilers would print the current file name if you provided more than one source file to compile.  GCC 7.2.0 doesn't seem to do that any more.  I so seldom compile multiple files in a single GCC invocation that I hadn't noticed the change.

Comment: CMake has all the ease of use of Make, and all the simplicity of parenthesized, backrefencing regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` is just a driver program which [uses `cc1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77779/relationship-between-cc1-and-gcc) to actually compile input C files.

That said, you can simply check arguments of `gcc` child processes to get what `gcc` is up to. I.e:

```
> gcc 1.c 2.c & ps -f --forest
[1] 22907
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
myaut    21963 18153  0 20:21 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash
myaut    22907 21963  0 20:41 pts/1    00:00:00  \_ gcc 1.c 2.c
myaut    22909 22907  0 20:41 pts/1    00:00:00  |   \_ 
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/cc1 -quiet 1.c -quiet -dumpbase
  1.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase 1 -o
myaut    22908 21963  0 20:41 pts/1    00:00:00  \_ ps -f --forest
```

In this example I was lucky enough to capture child process which actually compiles 1.c with `ps` which has started almost simultaneously with `gcc`

---

Anyway, using a full fledged building system on top of GCC (make, CMake or SCons) is a much better for compiling project consisting of multiple files.

Comment: CMake uses make under the hood. It is more of a confuguration layer on top of make. It is not a build-tool itself.